# BottomNavigationView with nested graph

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem in my application when using nested graph in my nave graph xml file
It's my nav_graph file

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@navigation/nav_entries">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_entries"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_states"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_calendar"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_more"/>

</navigation>
```

and this is fragment container view in activity_main

```
 <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

And this is code from main activity to setup bottom navigation view with nave controller

```
 private fun setupUi() {
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController()
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
```

But when I run the app, It will crash and this is error :

```
navigation destination com.iranmobiledev.moodino:navigation/nav_entries is not a direct child of this NavGraph
```

Help me to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incorrect.
In navigation, not all nested navigation graphs should be defined with include, and a node(fragment) should be defined as the start destination. You can define other fragments in the nested navigation graph and use it with the include tag.
Use this code:

```
app:startDestination="@id/first_fragment_id">
```

Instead of:

```
app:startDestination="@navigation/nav_entries">
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

instead of adding the graph in xml, inflate it programmatically.
the issue will be resolved.